# codecs error while reading a file in python 3.4.2

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Python3.4.2 and I see the below error, I have included the encoding type utf-8 and still see the error.

```
File "C:\Python34(1)\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode     
   return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
   UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 6389:
   character maps to <undefined>
```

This is the code which reads the file. The file is a huge one and the error is thrown at line 916355

```
with open(filename) as infile:
    lc = 0
    for line in infile:
        lc = lc +1
        print (lc)
```

line `916355` and `916356` in my file are as below,

```
2015 Jun 30 05:06:09.073049 igmp [7214]: : Received General v2 Query from 40.150.3.1 (Eth3/1), mrt: 10 sec
2015 Jun 30 05:06:11.429282 igmp [7214]: : Send v2 Report for 224.0.1.39 on Eth3/1
```

Comment: Please show the code that code the actual reading, because the error clearly indicates that the file is still read with the system code page (CP1252).

Comment: Hi dhke thanks for you quick response, I have added the code information above

Comment: I'm guessing, but is line 23 in your code the the one with the function `print()`? If so: Try `print(lc.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, 'ignore'))` and check if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You *have not* "included the encoding type utf-8."  If you did, your code would look like this:

```
with open(filename, encoding='utf8') as infile:  # Put the encoding here
    lc = 0
    for line in infile:
        lc = lc +1
        print (lc)
```

But that's not enough.  Unfortunately, the Windows terminals are not capable of full Unicode.  They can usually handle one code page at a time, but not the full range of Unicode all at once.

If this is just for debugging, you might try something like this:

```
print(lc.encode('ascii', errors='backslashescape').decode('ascii'))
```

That will convert Unicode characters into backslash-escaped sequences (`\u1234` = U+1234), and pass ASCII characters through unchanged.

If you actually care about this output, you will need to decide what encoding you want to use and how you want to output it.  It may be easier to write to a file in UTF-8, then open that file with a Unicode-aware text editor (Notepad can be told to open files in UTF-8, in the open dialog box).